# Ad hoc Updates to System Catalogs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I know this question has been addressed elsewhere, but I cannot figure this out.

I have this view:

```
SELECT       t.name AS 'TableName' 
        ,c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
        ,SEP.VALUE as 'DETAILS'      
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
left join sys.extended_properties sep on t.object_id = sep.major_id
                                     and c.column_id = sep.minor_id
                                     and sep.name = 'MS_Description'
```

And when I run this query, I get the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM [VIEW] WHERE DETAILS IS NOT NULL
```

However, There was a description I added to one of the columns through the table designer that I later removed. My issue is that this row still returns with my query, with DETAILS displayed as an empty string. I would like for this row to no longer show up, so I ran:

```
UPDATE sys.extended_properties SET VALUE=null WHERE major_id=1781581385 AND minor_id=4
```

To which I get the following error:

```
Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
```

I have tried Setting the Database to single user, as suggested by Martin1 here:
https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/40909/ad-hoc-update-to-system-catalogs-is-not-supported.html

I feel I am missing something simple, and would appreciate any feedback. Again, I apologize for the duplicate thread.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but can you run a delete instead of an update?  I'll do more research on this, but if you are missing something simple that would be my guess.  You might also run cleanup / maintenance on the database in question; that sometimes removes strange issues like this that don't seem to be logical.

Comment: I have tried running a delete, with the same results. I am unsure what you are referencing in regards to a cleanup (I'm kinda self-taught/Still learning SQL,) but I did run 
        EXEC sp_clean_db_free_space
 with no change to the query results

Comment: I wasn't able to remove the row, but I ended up modifying my view to hide this row using the following where clause:`WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),SEP.VALUE) != SPACE(20)`